# Single Address Linked to Multiple Users Even when Using OneToOneField(User)

Tags: django, django-views

So the problem I'm having is that when I add an address for a user, that address is being linked to all other users as well. I can see this also in my admin interface.

And then even if I login as one user, edit the address, the address for my second user is changed as well.

Any clues/hints to where my problem lies is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
# Create your models here.

class UserAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    phone =  models.CharField(max_length=120)
    shipping = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    billing = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_address()

    def get_address(self):
        return "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s" %(self.address, self.city, self.state, self.country, self.zipcode)
```

views.py

```
def edit_address(request):

    user = request.user
    address = UserAddress.objects.get(user=user) 

    form = UserAddressForm(request.POST or None, instance=address)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user_address = form.save(commit=False)

            user_address.user = request.user
            user_address.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s'%(reverse('address')))

    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "edit_address.html", context)

def add_address(request):
    form = UserAddressForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user_address = form.save(commit=False)

            user_address.user = request.user
            user_address.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s'%(reverse('address')))

    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "add_address.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies at that line:

```
address = UserAddress.objects.get()
```

As you do you not specify query parameters when trying to retrieve the address, Django retrieves the only address that you have in your database (if you had more than one or no address, it would fail). So you are always editing the same object.

I guess that what you are trying to do is:

```
address = UserAddress.objects.get(user=user)
```

Which will retrieve the address for the user.
It is assuming that the user does have an address, if he does not, it will fail.

Comment: Thanks aumo! That worked. I was trying that, but your explanation about needing to have an address already existing was my problem.

I created two views (add_address, edit_address). Everything is working fine, but would it be better practice to just combine the two views into one?

Using a try/except or 'if statement'?

I've updated my code above.

Comment: Well if the logic is exactly the same, indeed combine it into one.